# Typescript module: Export interface and all its props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, module, interface

I have a module with multiple functions exported. My module declaration looks like this:

```
declare module 'my-module' {
  export function getUserAvailablePaymentMethods(requestData: {
    merchantId: number,
  }): Promise<any>

  // etc...
}
```

This works great. Altough, I'd also want to export an interface from this module with the same functions. Like this:

```
declare module 'my-module' {
  export interface InjectedActions {
    getUserAvailablePaymentMethods: (requestData: {
      merchantId: number,
    }) => Promise<any>
  }

  export function getUserAvailablePaymentMethods(requestData: {
    merchantId: number,
  }): Promise<any>

  // etc...
}
```

The reason for this is that I sometimes want to type my react components and then I need an interface.

**The problem**

I don't want to write all the functions twice like I do in my example. I've tried doing this:

```
declare module 'my-module' {
  export function getUserAvailablePaymentMethods(requestData: {
    merchantId: number,
  }): Promise<any>

  export interface InjectedDevcodeActions {
    getUserAvailablePaymentMethods: getUserAvailablePaymentMethods
  }
  // etc...
}
```

But this is not working. I get: "Cannot find name 'getUserAvailablePaymentMethods'.".

Is it possible to achieve this without writing the functions twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `getUserAvailablePaymentMethods` cannot be used directly as a type.  Use `typeof` if you want its type:

```
declare module 'my-module' {
  export function getUserAvailablePaymentMethods(requestData: {
    merchantId: number,
  }): Promise<any>

  export interface InjectedDevcodeActions {
    getUserAvailablePaymentMethods: typeof getUserAvailablePaymentMethods
  }
  // etc...
}
```

[This issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27630) is for a better error message.